# Python: Object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

Here in my code I generate combinations of numbers, after that I shuffle them and want to pop each element at once and do some operations with it, but when I'm trying to pop an element I'm getting an error like ***"x = lst[0][0]
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable".***
What is the problem could you help me please as I'm really new to python.
Thank you!

```
temp = []

while i<=value:
    while j<=value:
        lst = [i,j]
        lst=list(itertools.combinations(lst,2))
        temp = temp+lst
        j=j+1
    i=i+1
    j=1

shuffle(temp)


while a<sqrvalue:
    lst = list(temp.pop())

    x = lst[0][0]
    y = lst[0][1]

    w1 = w*(x-1)
    w2 = w*x

    h1 = h*(y-1)
    h2 = h*y
```

Comment: Print out the value of `lst`. The first element is already an int

Comment: `lst = [i,j];lst=list(itertools.combinations(lst,2))` results in `lst = [(i, j)]` because there is only one two-length combination of a two item list.  What are you really trying to accomplish with those two while-loops at the top?  What does `temp` have in it to start with?

Comment: What does it mean? @StevenRumbalski

Comment: i want to get combinations of numbers from 1 to value

Comment: in this code my output is " [[(4, 2)], [(4, 4)], [(2, 2)], [(1, 4)], [(1, 3)], [(3, 4)], [(1, 2)], [(4, 3)], [(2, 4)], [(3, 2)], [(2, 1)], [(1, 1)], [(3, 3)], [(3, 1)], [(2, 3)], [(4, 1)]]"
but i can not pop from this list

Comment: `lst = [i, j]` is a two item list.  It contains `i` and `j`.  So if `i` were `2` and `j` were `3` after `lst = [i, j]` `lst` would contain `[2, 3]`.  After `lst=list(itertools.combinations(lst,2))`, `lst` would contain `[(2, 3)]`.

Comment: I do not understand what is the problem?@StevenRumbalski

Comment: `list(itertools.permutations(range(1, 5), 2))` gives `[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 1), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 4), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3)]` without the annoying sublists and states what you mean without ambiguity.  Then drop those first to while loops entirely.  The problem is that you are making a superfluous call to `itertools.combinations` that literally does nothing.  You could leave that line out and replace the previous line with `lst = [(i, j)]`.  The result would be the same.  It made your code hard to read because I expected the line to have meaning.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski here list(itertools.permutations(range(1, 5), 2)) gives [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 1), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 4), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3)] i need also numbers like (1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4). Is there a way to do that?

Comment: `itertools.product(range(1, 5), 2))` will give you repeats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned in the comments you are expect `temp` to have the structure:

```
[[(4, 2)], [(4, 4)], [(2, 2)], [(1, 4)], [(1, 3)], ... ]
```

But instead it has the structure:

```
[(4, 2), (4, 4), (2, 2), (1, 4), (1, 3), ... ]
```

When you pop an item from `temp` you try to do

```
lst = list(temp.pop()) 
x = lst[0][0]
y = lst[0][1]
```

when instead you should do

```
lst = list(temp.pop()) # lst is a two item tuple
x = lst[0]
y = lst[1]
```

or even better

```
x, y = temp.pop() # this is called tuple unpacking
```

The reason `temp` had the structure that it does is that was built with

```
temp = temp+lst
```

Since `temp` is a list and `lst` is a list containing a single tuple `[(1, 3)]` the result is a new list with a tuple added to the end.  To create the data structure you were imagining you would have wanted `temp.append(lst)`, but as discussed in comments you should just do:

```
import random
import product

temp = list(itertools.product(range(1, 5), 2))
random.shuffle(temp)
```